# MySQL get user data from 2 different IDs using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

Edit: I don't understand why this got downvoted, but it is an actual question that seems to abide the SO rules.

I am trying to make a very simple message system. I have a simple `messages` table which contains `to_id`, `from_id` and the `message`. I also have a `users` table which contains the `id` of the user and the `profile_pic` of the user. Now I'm trying to retrieve the messages and the profile pic for each user using an SQL query with `JOIN` but I am having an error and I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `messages`.`from_id`, `messages`.`to_id`, `messages`.`message`
INNER JOIN `users`.`profile_pic` AS `from_pic`  on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
INNER JOIN `users`.`profile_pic` AS `to_pic`  on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
FROM `messages` WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

Here's the error I'm getting from Phpmyadmin:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `users`.`profile_pic` AS `from_pic`  on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`fr' at line 2
```

Comment: 1) You should in include the error text in your question 2) It's likely a syntax error, your `INNER JOIN` clauses need to come _after_ the `FROM` clause and before the `WHERE` clause

Comment: @jmoerdyk Added error

Comment: Why did you get downvoted?  The error message says it all: "check the manual...".

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have a syntax error.  The `FROM` clause needs to come *before* the `INNER JOIN` clauses:

```
SELECT `messages`.`from_id`, `messages`.`to_id`, `messages`.`message`
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN `users`.`profile_pic` AS `from_pic`  on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
INNER JOIN `users`.`profile_pic` AS `to_pic`  on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

Comment: But now the error is `#1146 - Table 'users.profile_pic' doesn't exist
`

Comment: Do a 'describe users' and post the result so we can see your table